# Have 07 cobalt ls check engine light on and now will only do 45 to 60 mph

Tags: chevrolet, cel, cobalt

Check engine light on cobalt came on and now will only do 45 to 60 mph any ideas

Comment: More details about the problem would be helpful. Also it's generally a good idea to provide at least basics like model, year, engine, mileage, etc.

Comment: Not much to go on there, but my first thought would be you're missing on one or more cylinders, or maybe catalytic converter.

Comment: A check engine light means an error code was generated, stored in memory for retrieval by reader or scantool. So by Autozone or other auto parts store offering free readings. Refrain from any suggestions unless it came from a certified ASE mechanic/technician. Post any error code(s).

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What codes are present when you check them?